# Detect current logged in user who made an ajax call to a socket

Tags: java, ajax, sockets

I have two users in my machine and I'm running a code that opens a ServerSocket on a specific port via an ajax call. What I'm trying to do is detect which user has opened the Socket.

For example: I'm current logged in with user "admin". 
                     So, I make an ajax call and it opens the ServerSocket. If I run System.getProperty("user.name") it returns "admin" as expected. 
                     But, when I change user to "lucas" and try to make an ajax call to the server, when I run System.getProperty("user.name") it stills return "admin" probably because the code is running on that user.

Knowing this, is there any way I could tell my server which user is making the ajax call?

Comment: You are wanting to to who performed an operation on a *remote* computer?

Comment: Aren't you just requiring logins? How are you authenticating currently?

Comment: No, the operation will happen on the same computer @Raedwald. 
I think getting the login is enough Evan Knowles (could not notify you with @). Actually, what I need is a way to identify uniquely who opened the ServerSocket.

Comment: How you're handling the Session? If you're storing the SessionId in cookie, then you can get the Cookie params in HttpServletRequest made by Ajax call.

Comment: @user1354678 we are not using Servlet to open the Socket but I guess the session ID will satisfy our purpose. We're gonna try to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Briefly, no. A socket has no information about who has opened it. You could track the host that has opened it, and that may be of use if you have a host/user mapping, but what I really think you want is some form of authentication for your clients. In that scenario, your user will open a socket and be challenged for identifying info. That will allow you to determine the user from the server's perspective.

Comment: The problem is that the host will always be the same (the code will be run always from the same computer but not always from the same user)

Comment: The I would refer you again to the authentication issue, which is the proper way to resolve this issue